# Coefficients of the $j$ function modulo a prime $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $j(q) = \sum_{n  \geq -1} c(n) q^n$ be the usual modular $j$ invariant.

Given a prime $p$, and a real number $x$, I am interested in the number $$\psi(p,x) = \# \{n \leq x,\ p \nmid c(n)\}.$$ I'd like to know what is proved, and what is conjectured, about the asymptotics of $\psi(p,x)$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$. I have spent a lot of time trying to skim the literature, but it is too abundant: I found many interesting papers concerning related questions, but no global picture emerges. So I decided to ask MO. Here are the two questions I ask:

> (1) Is it known that for all $p$, $\psi(p,x)$ goes to infinity with $x$?
>
> (2) Has someone conjectured that $\psi(p,x) \gg x$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$? (and if so, is it known in any case ?)

**What I know:** The answer to (1) is yes if $p=2$ or if $p\geq 13$.
For $p=2$, it is proven in a paper of Zanello (Journal of Number Theory
Volume 151, June 2015, Pages 107–115), that $\psi(2,x) \geq x^{1/2}(\log \log x)/(\log x)$. If $p \geq 13$, then it is not hard to show that $U_p j$ is a non-constant $p$-adic modular form, hence congruent to a classical form mod p, and one obtains $\psi(p,x) \gg x/(\log x)^{3/4} $. But when $p=3,5,7,11$, I do not know the answer to question (1).

For the conjecture (2), I have only seen it conjectured for $p=2$, in a paper of Alfes who attributes the conjecture to Ken Ono, without reference.

Comment: A minor point, affecting only $p=3$ (in a minor way) - do you mean $J=j/1728$? I think this is standard notation - at least it is this way on the OEIS page for [A000521](https://oeis.org/A000521)

Comment: If (1) is false then $j$ would be a rational function of $q$ in char $p$. I've proved (J Number Theory 58 (1996) 55-59) that $j$ is in fact transcendental over ${\mathbb F}_p(q)$.

Comment: Why can we not proceed with the $U_p$ trick for all $p$? We can think of $j$ as an overconvergent weight 0 form with a pole at the cusp, so $U_p(j)$ also has this property, but it's holomorphic at the cusp, so it's overconvergent weight 0 with no poles, so congruent to a classical form mod $p$ (you don't even need overconvergence right, you just need that it's a $p$-adic form). Why do you restrict to $p\geq13$ -- what am I missing? If the reduction is identically zero then you can just divide by $p$ because of the $q$-expansion principle, right?

Comment: @znt. Good question. The problem is that $U_p j$ is indeed over convergent weight 0 with no poles for all $p$, but for $p<13$, it is actually the constant 744 (see Serre, Divisibilité de certaines fonctions arithmétiques, exercises). For $p \geq 13$, $U_p j$ is a form of filtration $p-1$ (loc. cit.) hence not a constant.

Comment: @Felipe. Quite interesting. (And I see how I missed this in my mathscinet search: all my query had the word coefficients in them).This might be an answer.

Comment: Joel -- in that case, you can use $j-744$ ;-)